# Ipset + Iptables. Варианты. Как будет лучше с точки зрения производительности?

Tags: iptables, ipset

Моя цель, это заблокировать несколько сотен тысяч разных подсетей. Хотел бы узнать, как это можно сделать максимально эффективно с точки зрения производительности.

**1 вариант:** создать 25 новых цепочек в Iptables и создать 25 списков Ipset (в каждом списке Ipset будет примерно по 5-10 тысяч подсетей)

**2 вариант:** создать 3 новые цепочки в Iptables и создать 3 списка Ipset (в каждом списке Ipset будет по 60.000 подсетей)

**Пример, как это будет работать у меня:**

Создаём цепочку в Iptables:

```
iptables -N RULE_48
```

Создаём правило. Перебрасываем на проверку все IP начиная с 48.0 и заканчивая 55.0

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 48.0.0.0/5 -j RULE_48
```

Добавим правило в цепочку DROP, которое ссылается на список в Ipset

```
iptables -A RULE_48 -m set --match-set block48 src -j DROP
```